What is the best practice to define a newcommand to derive the projection of the curve intersection with specific x-axis notation?
I encounter a confusing problem when deal with the projection of the function figure as below. I wonder how to modify my tex code's definition of \newcommand{\ShowIntersectionsAndVerticalLine} with 4 arguments:

name path global1
name path global2
the color of the intersection
the notation of the x-axis (as in the figure x_1 x'_1 etc.).

I found similar brilliant answer as below, but they didn't fit my case.
Intersection -| of a named and a calculated coordinate
TiKz-pgf: Project intersection points in the abscissa axis
What I want to get is shown below:

Here below is my MWE of the problem.
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\tikzset{elegant/.style={smooth,thick,samples=50}}
% Define this as a command to ensure that it is same in both cases
\newcommand*{\ShowIntersection}[3]{
\fill 
    [name intersections={of=#1 and #2, name=i, total=\t}] 
    [#3, opacity=1, every node/.style={above left, black, opacity=1}] 
    \foreach \s in {1,...,\t}{(i-\s) circle (1pt)};
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            axis x line = middle,
            axis y line = middle,
            xmin = -1,
            xmax = 4,
            ymin = -1,
            ymax = 3
        ]
        \addplot[elegant,domain=-4:4,name path global=A]{(x-1)*ln(x)-x+1} node [left=2pt] {$f(x)$};
        \addplot[blue,mark=*,mark size=1pt] coordinates {(1,0)};
        \addplot[blue,mark=*,mark size=1pt] coordinates {(e,0)};
        \addplot[blue,thick,name path global=B]{-x+1};
        \addplot[blue,thick,name path global=C]{(1-1/e)*x-e+1};
        \addplot[orange,thick,name path global=D] coordinates {(-1,0.5) (4,0.5)};
        \ShowIntersection{A}{D}{orange}
        \ShowIntersection{B}{D}{blue}
        \ShowIntersection{C}{D}{blue}
        %%  TBC
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Welcome to TeX.SE!

You can add \forloop settings as optional argument.
With the syntax \ShowIntersection[<projections>]{<path 1>}{<path 2>}{<color>}, it can be defined with
\NewDocumentCommand{\ShowIntersection}{ ommm }{
  \filldraw
  [name intersections={of=#2 and #3, name=i, total=\t}]
  [#4, opacity=1, every node/.style={above left, black, opacity=1}]
  \foreach \s in {1,...,\t} { (i-\s) circle (1pt) }
  \IfValueT{#1}
    {
      \foreach \s / \nodecontent in {#1}
        {
          (i-\s) edge[#4, dashed] (i-\s |- 0,0)
          (i-\s |- 0,0) node
          [color=#4, below=1em, anchor=base, font=\footnotesize]
          {$\nodecontent$}
        }
    }
  ;
}

In this way:

\ShowIntersection{A}{D}{orange} works as before,
\ShowIntersection[1/x_1, 2/x_2]{A}{D}{orange} marks the first intersection with x_1 and the second with x_2 (so you can use A and B if you need),
\ShowIntersection[2/x]{A}{D}{orange} marks only the second intersection.

But you loose the automatic numbering provided by the NBur answer.
As it, with your example, the labels overlap. So maybe you can also add a last parameter to shift horizontally each label
\NewDocumentCommand{\ShowIntersection}{ ommm }{
  \filldraw
  [name intersections={of=#2 and #3, name=i, total=\t}]
  [#4, opacity=1, every node/.style={above left, black, opacity=1}]
  \foreach \s in {1,...,\t} { (i-\s) circle (1pt) }
  \IfValueT{#1}
    {
      \foreach \s / \nodecontent / \nodexshift in {#1}
        {
          (i-\s) edge[#4, dashed] (i-\s |- 0,0)
          (i-\s |- 0,0) node
          [color=#4, below=1em, anchor=base, font=\footnotesize, xshift=\nodexshift]
          {$\nodecontent$}
        }
    }
  ;
}

Example :
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\tikzset{elegant/.style={smooth,thick,samples=50}}

% Define this as a command to ensure that it is same in both cases
\NewDocumentCommand{\ShowIntersection}{ ommm }{
  \filldraw
  [name intersections={of=#2 and #3, name=i, total=\t}]
  [#4, opacity=1, every node/.style={above left, black, opacity=1}]
  \foreach \s in {1,...,\t} { (i-\s) circle (1pt) }
  \IfValueT{#1}
    {
      \foreach \s / \nodecontent / \nodexshift in {#1}
        {
          (i-\s) edge[#4, dashed] (i-\s |- 0,0)
          (i-\s |- 0,0) node
          [color=#4, below=1em, anchor=base, font=\footnotesize, xshift=\nodexshift]
          {$\nodecontent$}
        }
    }
  ;
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      axis x line = middle,
      axis y line = middle,
      xmin = -1,
      xmax = 4,
      ymin = -1,
      ymax = 3
    ]
    \addplot[elegant,domain=-4:4,name path global=A]{(x-1)*ln(x)-x+1} node [left=2pt] {$f(x)$};
    \addplot[blue,mark=*,mark size=1pt] coordinates {(1,0)};
    \addplot[blue,mark=*,mark size=1pt] coordinates {(e,0)};
    \addplot[blue,thick,name path global=B]{-x+1};
    \addplot[blue,thick,name path global=C]{(1-1/e)*x-e+1};
    \addplot[orange,thick,name path global=D] coordinates {(-1,0.5) (4,0.5)};

    \ShowIntersection[1/x_1/2pt, 2/x_2/-2pt]{A}{D}{orange}
    \ShowIntersection[1/x'_1/-2pt]{B}{D}{blue}
    \ShowIntersection[1/x'_2/2pt]{C}{D}{blue}

  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


[Edit] Starred variant with automatic numbering
Here is a new definition with also provides automatic numbering, when used with a star:
\NewDocumentCommand{\ShowIntersection}{ sommm }{
  \filldraw
  [name intersections={of=#3 and #4, name=i, total=\t}]
  [#5, opacity=1, every node/.style={above left, black, opacity=1}]
  \foreach \s in {1,...,\t} { (i-\s) circle (1pt) }
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
  {% starred version
    \foreach \s in {1,...,\t}
    {
      (i-\s) edge[#5, dashed] (i-\s |- 0,0)
      (i-\s |- 0,0) node
      [color=#5, below=1em, anchor=base, font=\footnotesize]
      {$\IfValueTF{#2}{#2}{x}_\s$}
    }
  }
  {% unstarred version
    \IfValueT{#2}
    {
      \foreach \s / \nodecontent / \nodexshift in {#2}
      {
        (i-\s) edge[#5, dashed] (i-\s |- 0,0)
        (i-\s |- 0,0) node
        [color=#5, below=1em, anchor=base, font=\footnotesize, xshift=\nodexshift]
        {$\nodecontent$}
      }
    }
  }
  ;% end of TikZ path command
}

This times (points 1 to 3 unchanged):

\ShowIntersection{A}{D}{orange} works as before,
\ShowIntersection[1/x_1/-2pt, 2/x_2/2pt]{A}{D}{orange} marks the first intersection with x_1 and the second with x_2 (so you can use A and B if you need),
\ShowIntersection[2/x/0pt]{A}{D}{orange} marks only the second intersection.
\ShowIntersection*[M]{A}{D}{orange} marks all intersections with M_1, M_2, ..., M_n.
\ShowIntersection*{A}{D}{orange} marks all intersections with x_1, x_2, ..., x_n.


Oh! Thanks u toooooooo much!

Using the second link, here is my attempt.
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\tikzset{elegant/.style={smooth,thick,samples=50}}
% Define this as a command to ensure that it is same in both cases
\NewDocumentCommand{\ShowIntersection}{mmmms}{
  \draw [
  name intersections={of=#1 and #2,name=i, total=\t}, thin, dotted, #3] 
  [every node/.style={#3,font=\tiny}]  
  \foreach \s in {1,...,\t}
  {
    (i-\s) node[fill,#3,circle,inner sep=0,minimum size=2pt]{} % dot in the intercection
    (i-\s) -- (i-\s |-{axis cs:0,0}) % line to projet from intesection to x-axis
    node [below,font=\tiny] {$#4\IfBooleanF{#5}{_{\s}}$}
  };
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      axis x line = middle,
      axis y line = middle,
      xmin = -1,
      xmax = 4,
      ymin = -1,
      ymax = 3
      ]
      \addplot[elegant,domain=-4:4,name path global=A]{(x-1)*ln(x)-x+1} node [left=2pt] {$f(x)$};
      \addplot[blue,mark=*,mark size=1pt] coordinates {(1,0)};
      \addplot[blue,mark=*,mark size=1pt] coordinates {(e,0)};
      \addplot[blue,thick,name path global=B]{-x+1};
      \addplot[blue,thick,name path global=C]{(1-1/e)*x-e+1};
      \addplot[orange,thick,name path global=D] coordinates {(-1,0.5) (4,0.5)};
      \ShowIntersection{A}{D}{orange}{x}
      \ShowIntersection{B}{D}{blue}{x'}
      \ShowIntersection{C}{D}{blue}{x'_2}*
      %%  TBC
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

which produces

I use a \NewDocumentCommand to have a starred version easily. In that case the name provided is used as is, otherwise it is subscripted with the number of the intersection.

Thanks for your extraordinary response, while I found that a little unfit for the notation x1 and x'_1, kind of disgraceful, maybe it can be better with smaller fontsize?

What's more, I found that the design of the newcommand is lack of extensions——which means that if I want to illustrate the many many intersections and projections with anotation A B C D..., the command looks not as smart as I think for the foreach loop in the \draw command, I also wonder weather we can assign each intersections and set the projections not in the \foreach loop freely. Thanks so much!

A bit more elaborate to code, but that's possible with expl3. Then you just have to pass a list as fourth arg.
